Is there a way to add open graph meta tags to pdf files uploaded to wordpress?
The problem:
I have to create a linkedin share with a custom description and preview image of a pdf file uploaded to a wordpress site via sftp. It is in a custom directory path. I am allowed to upload the pdf via the media uploader. However, I still can't figure out how to add meta tags as the page is generated by the browser. Most of the seo plugins allow you to create meta tags for posts and pages but not an actual pdf media file.
I have tried using linkedin's api to create a share button where I can add the custom description and image. The problem is that requires the user to login first and the goal is to have the same share experience that exists with the existing default share button. Essentially click it, see a preview of what would share and click post without having to login or give permissions to the site to post on your behalf etc.
